# QML: TableView динамическое изменение высоты строк

Tags: qml, tableview

Здравствуйте, имеется QTableView из нескольких колонок. В некоторых из них находится текст, где то комбобоксы, а где то еще и картинки. Соответственно делегат отрисовки элементов находится внутри TableViewColumn. Необходимо изменять высоту строки чтобы текст в нее поместился полностью (при изменение ширины колонки изменяю ширину и текста находящегося внутри колонки, что приводит к изменение его высоты (wrap text)) Как мне динамически изменять высоту строки?

Вот TableViewColumn

```
TableViewColumn {
id: fullNameColumn
property int minColWidth: 175
property int maxColWidth: 500
role: "fullName"
title: "ФИО"
width: 360
property string imageSource : ""
onWidthChanged: {
   if (width < minColWidth)
       width = minColWidth
}

delegate: Rectangle{
    id: rowCellContentFullName
    color: "transparent"
    Text {
        property int maxColWidth: 400
        id: labelFullName
        objectName: "labelFullName"
        font.pixelSize: 13
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        anchors.leftMargin: 38
        anchors.left: parent.left
        horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        visible: parent.visible
        width: parent.width - this.anchors.leftMargin * 2
        text: styleData.value !== undefined ? styleData.value : ""
        color: "#474747"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering     
}
```

}

Делегат отрисовки строки RowDelegate

```
property Component rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            id: rowDel
            objectName: "RowDelegate"
            height: parent.parent.children[1].children[2].children[0].children[0].height < 50 ? 50 : parent.parent.children[1].children[2].children[0].children[0].height
            property color selectedColor: styleData.hasActiveFocus ? primaryColor : secondaryColor
            property bool selectionMaskVisible
            property bool selected: false
    }
```

Как Вы можете увидеть, у меня получилось динамически изменить высоту строки используя "супер" выражение, но во первых при изменение структуры компонента, это выражение может не сработать, во вторых она работает только для 3 колонки, и если я эту колонку перенесу в другое место (на 1 или 5 место) то эта логика для нее уже не будет срабатывать, в дополнении необходимо изменять размер не только на основе одной ячейки, но и на основе других. Например: изменили 3 колонку, высота стала 100, изменили 2 колонку и пока она меньше чем 100, не менять как только стала больше сразу поменять, ну и собственно в обратную сторону.

Надеюсь что существует какой-либо "нативный" способ решения данной проблемы, а не такой "костыль" который я нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще решил проблему следующим образом. При изменении высоты текста, заношу эту высоту с инфой о колонке и строке в словарик. И при изменении ширины rowDelegate пересчитываю высоту исходя из максимальной высоты компонента во всех колонках строки.